# How can parameters be passed between tabs in a tab container in SAP Advanced Workflow

Tags: groovy, workflow, sap-business-technology-platform

I'm new to SAP workflow. I'm using a tab container in my form. I need to pass values across the tabs in it such that when Next/save button is clicked it will pass to the next tab in the container. I tried with Custom Params. Created the params first as category "Other" then changed it to "Workflow" but still can't access them from my script. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Which SAP workflow solution are you talking about? In which SAP software is it?

Comment: It is the web version under SAP commissions. For my case it is provided by callidusOnDemand.

Comment: I guess you mean SAP [Advanced Workflow](https://help.sap.com/docs/Advanced_Workflow) which is part of SAP BTP, so I have updated the title and tags accordingly.

Comment: As the tabs are part of the same container and the same screen so the parameters are readily available across the tabs. I have checked that from the groovy scripts and printed their values in the logs. So, this question can be closed now.

Comment: Thanks. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) how you can do it.